# Can I define a function in embeded javascript file of a asp.net server control to access Page Load event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have designded a asp.net server control that have an embeded javascript file.

```
document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back").style.left = 0;
document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back").style.top = 0;
document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back").style.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back").style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
document.getElementById("tbl_Messages").style.left = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - 250) / 2;
document.getElementById("tbl_Messages").style.top = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - 120) / 2;
function btn_Close() {
    document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back").style.visibility = "collapse";
    document.getElementById("tbl_Messages").style.visibility = "collapse";
}
```

I want the first 6 line of my javascript file run at runtime. But I recieve error at runtime:
Error: Object Required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload= function(){
    var divMessagesBack = document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back");
    divMessagesBack.style.left = 0;
    divMessagesBack.style.top = 0;
    divMessagesBack.style.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    divMessagesBack.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById("tbl_Messages").style.left = (document.documentElement.clientWidth - 250) / 2;
    document.getElementById("tbl_Messages").style.top = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - 120) / 2;
}

function btn_Close() {
    document.getElementById("div_Messages_Back").style.visibility = "collapse";
    document.getElementById("tbl_Messages").style.visibility = "collapse";
}
```

**P.S:** Since it is an ASP.Net control, the ID's of the controls might get changed once it renders as HTML. Hence add the code to render the **ClientID's** of the controls in the JS to avoid any further issues with the elements/object not found.